# Dynamic method binding

Tags: c++, dynamic-binding

```
class Shape {
public:
virtual void draw() = 0;
. . .
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
void draw() { . . . }
. . .
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
public:
void draw() { . . . }
. . .
};

class Square : public Rectangle {
public:
void draw() { . . . }
. . .
};


Rectangle* rect = new Rectangle;

rect->draw(); // Statically bound to the draw in the Rectangle class
```

In a text book , "concepts of programming language, 10th",

there's a part about dynamic method binding.

i think the type of the object pointed by rect can't be resolved statically because rect is polymorhpic reference type.
rect might also reference Sqaure type object in run time.

the last line above the code is incorrect??

Comment: i fixed it , there's errat

Comment: A sufficiently smart optimizer may be able to prove that `rect` always points to an instance of `Rectangle` in this example, and bind to `Rectangle::draw` statically. Either way, the observable effect is the same, so it's not clear why you would care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, because draw() is a virtual method, `rect->draw()` will always consult the `vtable` of the `Rectangle`-derived object being pointed to by `rect`.

*However*

If the compiler can prove that the `rect` is actually pointing at an instance of a `Rectangle` and not some other class which is derived from it which overrides the `draw()` method, then it is allowed (but not required) to bypass the polymorphic lookup, thus saving a couple of memory fetches.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example

```
int main
{
    Shape* cir = new Circle;
    Shape* rec = new Rectangle;
    Shape* sqr = new Square;

    cir->draw();    // Circle::draw
    rec->draw();    // Rectangle::draw
    sqr->draw();    // Square::draw
}
```

All of these variables `cir`, `rec`, and `sqr` are `Shape*`, but they will invoke their respective `draw` method due to polymorphism. This is even more clear when we re-use the same variable

```
int main
{
    Shape* shape = new Circle;
    shape->draw();  // Circle::draw
    delete shape;

    shape = new Rectangle;
    shape->draw();  // Rectangle::draw
    delete shape;

    shape = new Square;
    shape->draw();  // Square::draw
    delete shape;
}
```

In this case, the `draw` function must be resolved during runtime because the underlying type of `shape` can be modified throughout the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with your code, for polymorphic classes `virtual` function calls are resolved at runtime using the virtual function table, in fact, that is called dynamic binding in `c++`.